# rabbitmq server start error

Tags: .net, windows, rabbitmq

I installed rabbitmq 3.2 on Windows a few days ago. Today, I uninstalled rabbitmq 3.2, and installed rabbitmq 3.6 instead. Things appeared to be OK after the installation until I started the RabbitMQ Windows Service, where after a few seconds, the service automatically stops. Checking the log, I see the following error report:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 8-Mar-2017::09:29:20 ===
Cluster upgrade needed but other disc nodes shut down after this one.
Please first start the last disc node to shut down.

Note: if several disc nodes were shut down simultaneously they may all
show this message. In which case, remove the lock file on one of them and
start that node. The lock file on this node is:

 c:/Users/chengong/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/RABBIT~1/nodes_running_at_shutdown 
=INFO REPORT==== 8-Mar-2017::09:29:20 ===
Error description:
   badarg

Log files (may contain more information):
   C:/Users/chengong/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/RABBIT~1.LOG
   C:/Users/chengong/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/RABBIT~2.LOG

Stack trace:
   [{io,format,
        [<0.54.0>,
         "\n\n****\n\nCluster upgrade needed but other disc nodes shut down after this one.\nPlease first start the last disc node to shut down.\n\nNote: if several disc nodes were shut down simultaneously they may all\nshow this message. In which case, remove the lock file on one of them and\nstart that node. The lock file on this node is:\n\n c:/Users/chengong/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/RABBIT~1/nodes_running_at_shutdown \n\n****\n\n\n",
         []],
        []},
    {rabbit_upgrade,die,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_upgrade.erl"},{line,200}]},
    {rabbit_upgrade,maybe_upgrade_mnesia,0,
                    [{file,"src/rabbit_upgrade.erl"},{line,145}]},
    {rabbit,'-boot/0-fun-0-',0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,271}]},
    {rabbit,start_it,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,403}]},
    {init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1076}]},
    {init,do_boot,3,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,784}]}]
```

I haven't configured anything additional to the defaults. The rabbitmq 3.6 service just won't run.

What can I do to resolve this problem? Thank you so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by doing what the error message suggested, and remove this file:

`c:/Users/chengong/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/RABBIT~1/nodes_running_at_shutdown`

restart RMQ after that and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for you help.I remove  c:/Users/chengong/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db .The problems have been solved. Thank you